# Passing variables between sibling blocks

Tags: templating, entries, craft3, frontend

Is there any possibility to use "entry" from the for-loop inside the "main" block inside another block ("header" in my case)? See example below:

```
{% extends "main" %}
    {% block header %}
        {{ entry.id }}
    {% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    {% for entry in craft.entries.section('blogPosts').limit(5).all() %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you want to achieve? In your example, the for loop would run 5 times so which `entry.id` do you want to get out?

The way to use common variables in both your blocks would be to do:

```
{% extends "main" %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('blogPosts').limit(5).all() %}

{% block header %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {# access entries in here #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {# and also in here #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "entry" variable used inside the loop is restricted to the loop only.

You could create a variable earlier in the process, outside the blocks, like so:

```
{%- set posts = craft.entries.section('blogPosts').limit(5).all() -%}
{%- extends "main" -%}
{%- block header -%}
    {%- for post in posts -%}
        {{- post.id -}}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endblock -%}

{%- block main -%}
    {%- for post in posts -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endblock -%}
```

Then loop through it where you need to.